# TimelinePlot with data above and below the line

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have to do a talk about how simulation and testing are coming together. So I have been developing a historical list of events in simulation and events in testing (please add to them if you wish).  The problem is I want to have the testing events above the timeline and the simulation events below the timeline. How do I do this?

Here are the two sets of data

```
test = {
   {{1947} -> "Flutter"},
   {{1940} -> "Tacoma Narrows"},
   {{1954} -> "Fatigue (Comet)"},
   {Interval[{{1912}, {2020}}] -> "Electronic Amplifiers"},
   {{1930} -> "Oscilloscope"},
   {Interval[{{1930}, {1985}}] -> "Analogue Testing"},
   {{1945} -> "Accelerometer"},
   {Interval[{{1985}, {2020}}] -> "Digital Testing"},
   {Interval[{{1975}, {2020}}] -> "Digital Signal Processing"},
   {{1965} -> "Fast Fourier Transform"},
   {Interval[{{1990}, {1986}}] -> "Codification of Testing"}
   }; 

simulation = {
   {Interval[{{1950}, {1990}}] -> "Main Frames"},
   {Interval[{{1900}, {1970}}] -> "Slide Rules"},
   {Interval[{{1970}, {1980}}] -> "Electronic Calculators"},
   {Interval[{{1985}, {2020}}] -> "Workstations"},
   {{1964} -> "NASTRAN"},
   {Interval[{{1983}, {2020}}] -> "NAFEMS"},
   {{1960} -> "Finite Element Analysis"},
   {{2006} -> "ASME Verification and Validation"}
   };
```

I can make individual plots

```
  TimelinePlot[test, AspectRatio -> 1/2, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}]
TimelinePlot[simulation, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I want is a common timeline with the test items above the line and the simulation items below the line. How do I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Show[
    TimelinePlot[#1,AxesOrigin->#2]&@@@{{test,Top},{simulation,Bottom}},
    AspectRatio->1/2,BaseStyle->{FontSize->12},
    PlotRange->All,Frame->False,Axes->{True,False}
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have it. Thanks