# Does Mathematica have a date region function together with operations like intersection?

Tags: date-and-time

Consider the following scenario.

Suppose I consider time range from `TimeObject[{18,30,0}]` to `TimeObject[{22,30,0}]` on Weekdays and `TimeObject[{18,0,0}]` to `TimeObject[{22,0,0}]` on Weekends as peak time for something.

Now given a date range `DateObject[{2019,7,18,20,12,30}]` to `DateObject[{2019,7,31,18,45,30}]`. I want to find the intervals of peak times encountered in this range. Also I want to find the proportion of time spend in peak? What is the easiest way to calculate this using the Mathematica's `Date` and `Time` functionality.

Does Wolfram language provide a symbolic wrapper to represent a date/time interval and also a disjoint but periodic intervals of time?

---

Thank you @kglr it works! Although `"Duration"` property does not exactly calculate what I want but the following workaround works.

```
With[{
    interval=DateTime`DateInterval[{3755358615, 3755368800}, {3755440800, 3755455200}, {3755527200, 3755540710}, True]
},
    {
        Query[Apply[Plus]@*All,Apply[Subtract]@*Reverse]@interval["Dates"],
        interval["Duration"],
        DateObject[{2019,1,1,19,10,15},"Instant","Gregorian",1.`]-DateObject[{2019,1,3,21,45,10},"Instant","Gregorian",1.`]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes ... there is (undocumented) `` DateTime`DateInterval ``:

```
di = DateTime`DateInterval[{DateObject[{2019, 7, 18, 1, 30, 0}] , 
       DateObject[{2019, 7, 18, 12, 30, 0}]}]
```

[image]

```
Options[DateTime`DateInterval]
```

> {CalendarType -> Automatic, TimeZone :> $TimeZone}

```
di["Properties"]
```

> {"CalendarType", "DateRange", "Dates", "DayCount", "Duration", "Max", "Min", "RawDates", "TimeZone"}

```
di /@ {"Min", "Max"}
```

[image]

```
di["Duration"]
```

> Quantity[0.458333, "Days"]

```
UnitConvert[di["Duration"], "Seconds"]
```

> Quantity[39600., "Seconds"]

Multiple intervals:

```
dilist = DateTime`DateInterval /@ 
   {{DateObject[{2019, 7, 18, 1, 30}] , DateObject[{2019, 7, 21, 12, 30}]}, 
    {DateObject[{2019, 7, 20, 2, 45}] , DateObject[{2019, 7, 22, 10, 30}]}};

Column @ dilist
```

[image]

Interval operations work the same way as for `Interval` objects:

```
IntervalIntersection @@ dilist
```

[image]

```
IntervalUnion @@ dilist
```

[image]

```
Show[TimelinePlot[Association /@ 
   (Column[Insert[DateObject /@ #[[1]], "thru", 2], Center] -> # & /@ dilist), 
     AxesOrigin -> Bottom],
 TimelinePlot[Association[
    Column[Insert[DateObject /@ #[[1]], "thru", 2], Center] -> # &[
     IntervalIntersection @@ dilist]], 
     AxesOrigin -> Top, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

**Note:**   Used [this answer by Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185920/125) to avoid label clutter in `TimelinePlot`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did not know about this undocumented functionality.

Comment: @Anton, I did not know  about it myself  till I tried  ``Names["*`*Date*Interval*"]``:)

Comment: @klgr I am near speechless that that actually worked. It tells you something about the consistency of Mathematica's naming scheme, and perhaps the number of functions existing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Since V 12.1 `DateInterval` is part of the language:

```
di = DateInterval[{DateObject[{2019, 7, 18}], DateObject[{2019, 8, 29}]}]
```

[image]

```
di["Properties"]
```

{"CalendarType", "DateBounds", "Dates", "Duration", "Granularity", "Max", "Min", "RawDates", "TimeZone"}

("Granularity" was added with V 13.3)

```
di /@ {"Min", "Max"}
```

[image]

```
TimelinePlot[di]
```

[image]